# How do I turn on Forged Transmit?

Tags: networking, server, vmware

I have Ubuntu 20.10 desktop and am using VMWare Workstation to setup a nested vSphere/ESXi test lab.
For VMs to be able to communicate from within these nested ESXi servers I need to turn on both Promiscuous Mode and Forged Transmit on the network port in Ubuntu 20.10.
From google I found out you can turn on promiscuous mode with "ip link set eth1 promisc on" but I can't find anything for turning on Forged Transmit?  Any ideas?